# Does "@media (min-width: 900px)" look at browser width or monitor width?

Tags: css, media-queries

On desktop browsers, when a CSS rule like "@media (min-width: 900px)" is set, is it looking at the browser width or the monitor width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser window usually. <s>There's no CSS way of checking monitor width.</s> [`device-width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#device-width) can target a specific width, but not a min max.

It's not even specific to browsers, but the display width of whatever media the content is being rendered to, including print media.

Comment: I thought the exact same thing, but when I shrink my browser to less than 900px wide, the "@media (min-width: 900px)" still takes effect. Why is that?

Comment: @user3163495 - your media query probably has an error in it, and isn't getting picked up properly.  Put in your question the _actual_ media query, with some sample CSS.  Better yet, create an [mcve].

Comment: Something else is happening. Could it be that your browser zoom level is not at actual size?